# Cannot telnet port 80 remotely, nginx

Tags: networking, 18.04, firewall, nginx

**MY problem is:**
I can `telnet` to port 80 locally, but not from another computer.

The following is what I did:

1. Disable firewall.

   ```
   $ufw disable
   ```
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   $netstat -tlpn |grep nginx
   ```

   Its result is:

   ```
   tcp    0     0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN 3274/nginx: master
   ```
3. Find my static IP address:

   ```
   $ifconfig
   ```
4. Execute

   ```
   $telnet my_static_ip_address 80
   ```

   successful
5. When I run this command from another PC

   ```
   C:\> telnet my_static_ip_address 80
   ```

   I get the error

   ```
   Connection is refused.
   ```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Does the other machine lock the port?